# identify perf's PID using top/ps

Tags: linux, process, pid, perf

I need to kill perf in a bash script using its PID. However, unable to identify perf's PID (using top). Any pointers appreciated. Ubuntu XX 16.04.2. Thanks.

Comment: found "pidof" command to be very useful in finding  PID. Then used         
    kill -SIGHUP $(pidof perf) to kill the process

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can grep ps for the process and get its id from there. then use the output from that with your kill command.

```
kill $(ps aux | awk '/perf/{print $2}')
```

Comment: This worked. Just needed to search for whole word perf and invert grep other PIDs including grep and perf shell command (stat).  $ ps aux | grep -w 'perf' | grep -v 'grep' | grep -v 'stat' | awk '{print $2}'      I feel stupid 'caz did not do a simple name search on ps :)

Comment: kill $(ps aux | awk '/perf/{print $2}')  also terminated the screen session that perf was running in

Comment: Use `pidof` and/org `pgrep` to find process of perf; not all processes with perf inside their "process name"